# Python - What is the purpose of defining the maximum string length in an SQLAlchemy model?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Just curious because it doesn't seem to stop a longer string from being stored in the DB like I expected it to.

Why even define it if it doesn't matter? (it must do something!)

```
class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(12))
    description = db.Column(db.String(120))
    copy = db.Column(db.String)
    voice = db.Column(db.String(24))
```

Comment: You're probably using SQLite, which doesn't enforce column lengths. Other databases (eg MySQL and PostgreSQL) *do* enforce this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You should probably put that as an answer since that is the correct answer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yep, SQLite. Sounds like this answers my question. What happens if I were using a DB which does enforce this and a larger than allocated string is committed?